# Скрипт для backup and restore БД

Tags: sql, postgresql

Требуется сделать резервную копию базы PostgreSQL на одной машине и восстановить её на второй.

Это все должно просходить после запуска батника.

Comment: Обратитесь к официальной документации: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pgdump.html

Comment: Сделай лучше репликацию

Comment: добро пожаловать на [ru.so]! здесь принята модель: вы задаёте вопрос, вам отвечают. переформулируйте, пожалуйста, то, что вы написали, так, чтобы это было вопросом, а не только изложением возникших у вас проблем и требований. исправления можно внести, нажав [edit] ниже текста (пока ещё не) вопроса.

Comment: @Alex: Могу предложить вам Docker-way, а именно [мой собранный контейнер PostgreSQL](https://github.com/romeOz/docker-postgresql#backuping) с бэкапом, проверкой бэкапа и восстановление из него. Полный бэкап (т.е. все БД-ых) осуществляется по протоколу репликации (утилита [pg_basebackup](http://goo.gl/HP142j)). Единственное замечание, необходим любой Linux дистрибутив, либо воспользоваться утилитами [boot2docker](http://boot2docker.io/), [Docker Machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/install-machine/) или [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html) для иных вендоров (ОСей).

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

в интернете есть как сделать, вот пример

```
REM ПРИМЕР СОЗДАНИЯ РЕЗЕРВНОЙ КОПИИ БАЗЫ ДАННЫХ POSTGRESQL
CLS
ECHO OFF
CHCP 1251

REM Установка переменных окружения
SET PGBIN=C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\8.4\bin\
SET PGDATABASE=mydb
SET PGHOST=localhost
SET PGPORT=5484
SET PGUSER=admin
SET PGPASSWORD=admin

REM Смена диска и переход в папку из которой запущен bat-файл
%~d0
CD %~dp0

REM Формирование имени файла резервной копии и файла-отчета
SET DATETIME=%DATE:~6,4%-%DATE:~3,2%-%DATE:~0,2% %TIME:~0,2%-%TIME:~3,2%-%TIME:~6,2%
SET DUMPFILE=%PGDATABASE% %DATETIME%.backup
SET LOGFILE=%PGDATABASE% %DATETIME%.log
SET DUMPPATH="Backup\%DUMPFILE%"
SET LOGPATH="Backup\%LOGFILE%"

REM Создание резервной копии
IF NOT EXIST Backup MD Backup
CALL "%PGBIN%\pg_dump.exe" --format=custom --verbose --file=%DUMPPATH% 2>%LOGPATH%

REM Анализ кода завершения
IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL%==0 GOTO Error
GOTO Successfull

REM В случае ошибки удаляется поврежденная резервная копия и делается соответствующая запись в журнале
:Error
DEL %DUMPPATH%
MSG * "Ошибка при создании резервной копии базы данных. Смотрите backup.log."
ECHO %DATETIME% Ошибки при создании резервной копии базы данных %DUMPFILE%. Смотрите отчет %LOGFILE%. >> backup.log
GOTO End

REM В случае удачного резервного копирования просто делается запись в журнал
:Successfull
ECHO %DATETIME% Успешное создание резервной копии %DUMPFILE% >> backup.log
GOTO End

:End
```

если нужно периодически запускать

schedule.bat

```
CLS
ECHO OFF
CHCP 1251
SCHTASKS /Create /RU SYSTEM /SC DAILY /TN "Резервное копирование" /TR "D:\Db\backup.bat" /ST 02:00:00
IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL%==0 MSG * "Ошибка при создании задачи резервного копирования."
```

[ссылка откуда я взял](http://victor-k-development.blogspot.com/2010/01/postgresql-batch.html)